# changing the output filenames in [split]

Tags: bash, split, terminal

I would like to split a huge text file into separate text files. I use:

```
split -l 1000 file.txt split_file
```

and I will get `split_fileaa`, `split_filebb`, etc.

How can I change the extension to be

`split_file0.txt, split_file1.txt, etc`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension

Comment: Although this question sounds off topic `split` is a truly as part of bash programming as any other bash tool. I'm voting ON topic here. /Bash programmer

Comment: As I'd like to add a better answer to this question, and POSIX text-processing functions/utilities are used by professional and enthusiast programmers, voting to reopen.

Comment: And I'd like to see this "better answer" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--additional-suffix` is what you need for the additional suffix :

```
split -l 1000 -d --additional-suffix=.txt file.txt split_file
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `-d` option for numeric suffixes.