# custom filename for output-file without using additional-suffix

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using

```
split -b 100KB -d $Old_File New_File_$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.dat
```

but, I am getting output as

```
New_File_$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.dat01
New_File_$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.dat02
```

I want output to be:

```
New_File_$YEAR$MONTH$DAY_01.dat
New_File_$YEAR$MONTH$DAY_02.dat
```

Does anyone know how to get this?
FYI- Additional suffix is not supported

Comment: The split command allows you to set a prefix and a suffix. The split command reads `split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]`, so the prefix is set in the command line and the suffix can be set with one of the options. So the command reads `split -b 100KB $Old_File New_Fule_$YEAR$MINTH$DAY_ --additional-suffix=".dat"`

Comment: in addition to @kvantour's comment ... a google search on `linux split output file name` brings up several hits, eg, [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549206) and [this SE Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626)

Comment: @kvantour $Day is now not reflecting in the splitted file. project_attributes_20210100.dat ,here 00 is the prefix , i want it as project_attributes_20210125_01.dat and so on

Comment: It is always handy to use braces, sorry about the earlier mistake: `split -b 100KB "${Old_File}" "New_File_${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}_" --additional-suffix=".dat"`

Comment: worked fine thanks a lot !!only that it  starts with 00 and not 01